# Phonegap how to tweet on behalf of user

Tags: twitter, cordova

Just a quick question. Is it possible to have a 1 time twitter login on my app and at certain points i can send a tweet as that user because they are logged in?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that this isn't possible as twitters oath needs backend auth..

And fack all you down voters, was it so hard to answer a simple question rather than downvote..